# Content imported with CsvBulkLoader in Silverstripe is not saved in the SiteTree table

Tags: silverstripe

I am using the CsvBulkLoader in silverstripe to import some blog posts. This works fine and I can see the imported blog posts in my website.

But the data is added to the SiteTree_Live table and not to the SiteTree table. So when I try to edit the posts in the admin panel. They are not there, I'm guessing it is because there are not imported to the SiteTree table.

Does anyone know a solution for this or recommend any other plugin to import data to SS?

Thank you!

Comment: Interesting, this sounds like a bug. Would you mind reporting it to https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/issues, please?